# Git refuses to switch branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

Git is refusing to switch branches under linux.

I have initialized my project. The python branch exists on linux and I can see it when I give this command:

`git branch -a | grep python
  remotes/origin/python`

But under linux git refuses to switch to the python branch.

Watch:

```
git branch
* master
```

Then I do:

```
git checkout python
```

Check the branch again:

```
git branch
* master
```

Try once more:

```
git checkout origin python
```

Check again, still under master:

```
git branch
* master
```

Try one last time:

```
git checkout --force python
```

Still in the same branch. I'm in master:

```
git branch
* master
```

I even tried deleting the whole directory and checking it out again. Same thing. I am unable to switch to the branch named `python` under linux.

On windows this works fine. I can switch back and forth. But I need to test on Linux as well.

Why isn't git honoring my command to switch branch?

Comment: What is the output of `git checkout python` ?

Comment: There is no output. I included all output from the commands I gave in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If **git branch** don't display the branch "python" you have a problem. Did you init your project ? In my case, that is example where git branch display two branchs in linux and windows. My secondary branch **"perso"** is present in **.git/refs/heads**. It works perfectly.

Going in your **.git/refs** and search python in the differents directory. If you don't see python,is that it does not exist.
[image: Git branch]

Comment: Yes, I can see that the python branch exists when I do a `git branch -a` on the linux machine: `git branch -a | grep python
  remotes/origin/python`

Comment: I did init the project.

Comment: OK @bluethundr. Add **phyton** in your first output in this case.

Comment: You also can try to merge your phyton branch with a new empty branch. Try it !

Answer (score 0):

Does the python branch exists?

Try

```
git checkout -b python.
```

-b will create the branch.

Comment: Yes, the python branch exists. Was I not clear when I said this? `On windows this works fine. I can switch back and forth. But I need to test on Linux as well.` Not being sarcastic at all. Just making sure I am communicating clearly.

Comment: What you see when you run `git branch --list`?

Comment: When you do `git branch -a | grep python`, I think you should see two outputs: `python` and `remotes/origin/python`.

Comment: If I do a `git branch --list
* master` all I see is the master. If I do a git branch -a then grep for python I do see the python branch: `git branch -a | grep python
  remotes/origin/python`. Still unable to switch to the branch named python.

Comment: Did you tried `git checkout -b python` because it looks like your branch python only exists in your remote project, not in your local one. If you want the content of a specific remote branch, you have to specify it when you are cloning/pulling.

Answer (score 0):

The branch should be pulled from the remote.

Try: `git pull origin python`

Then check out to it.

Comment: Thanks! I am able to get a response when I do a `git pull origin python`. This is what I see: `git pull origin python
From ssh://git.us.companyworld.company.com:7999/~tdunphy/aws_scripts
 * branch            python     -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 86fe192..a047750
Fast-forward
 aws_iam_utils.py | 480 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++--
 aws_iam_utils.sh |  16 +-
 2 files changed, 470 insertions(+), 26 deletions(-)`. But when I try to change branches to python, nothing is still happening. I am stuck on master!

Comment: What do you see with `git remote -v`?

Comment: I see this: `origin ssh://git@git.us.compayworld.company.com:7999/~tdunphy/aws_scripts.git (fetch)
origin ssh://git@git.us.compayworld.company.com:7999/~tdunphy/aws_scripts.git (push)`

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout python` is supposed to generate some output like this:

```
Branch 'python' set up to track remote branch 'python' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'python'
```

The command `git checkout origin python` should give you an error like this:

```
error: pathspec 'python' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

If there is **no** output from both commands either your git is very broken OR -- much more likely -- you don't see the output of STDERR because it is redirected somewhere else.

You can test it like this (assuming a standard `bash` shell):

```
echo 1>&2 Hello World
```

If there is no output, then your terminal/shell is borked. If there is an output, then "only" git's error outputs are swalled. In that case you can do

```
git checkout python 2>&1
```

to see the output (since `git branch -a` works STDIN is visible).

Comment: Thanks! Yes, those commands were definitely not giving any output. But then I tried doing 'git fetch -a' and the python branch (and others) showed up. Now I can switch to them.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, using a visual tool can be quite helpful. There is no shame in it. Have you tried a tool like GitKraken? It is available for Linux.